# Kivy using Canvas: Key error with line while starting beyond boundaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, keyerror

I'm creating simple drawing app with Kivy. I'm realizing drawing by this code:

```
class Paint(Widget):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1, 1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, mode='hsv')
            d = 10.
            if touch.y > self.height:
                Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
                touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=[touch.x, touch.y], width=5)
            else:
                pass

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if touch.y > self.height:
            touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
        else:
            pass
```

The "if" statement is for ignoring touch input that is out of my area of drawing but still in-app window.
When I start drawing in the right area everything works fine even when I go out of boundaries.

**The error occurs when I start drawing outside the area and go into it.
These are logs I'm getting:**

> [INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/kivytest.py", line 46, in 
> MainApp().run()
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/app.py",
> line 855, in run
> runTouchApp()
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/base.py",
> line 504, in runTouchApp
> EventLoop.window.mainloop()
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py",
> line 747, in mainloop
> self._mainloop()
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py",
> line 479, in _mainloop
> EventLoop.idle()
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/base.py",
> line 342, in idle
> self.dispatch_input()
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/base.py",
> line 327, in dispatch_input
> post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/base.py",
> line 233, in post_dispatch_input
> listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
> File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/**init**.py",
> line 1404, in on_motion
> self.dispatch('on_touch_move', me)
> File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/**init**.py",
> line 1430, in on_touch_move
> if w.dispatch('on_touch_move', touch):
> File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py",
> line 560, in on_touch_move
> if child.dispatch('on_touch_move', touch):
> File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 707, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch
> File "/home/igor/PycharmProjects/kivytest/kivytest.py", line 30, in on_touch_move
> touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
> KeyError: 'line'

Thanks for help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is simply exactly what it says: in the case where the touch starts outside your widget's boundaries, you don't set `touch.ud['line']` to anything, therefore that key does not exist when you try to access it later.

Ultimately you should code it to do whatever you want (e.g. you might want to start the line when the touch is moved into your boundaries), but the most straightforward fix would be to check if `touch.ud['line']` exists before trying to do anything.